# How to send array of objects in retrofit multipart request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I want to send array objects with multipart data. I tried many ways but it is not working. My issue with the contributor parameter. Server says. contributor.0.id is required & contributor.0.role is required and so on for remaining items in the list. Server reads that there is a contributor array and it has items but he can't extract it for some reason.[image: Here is how it works on postman (POST/form-data) I can't do the same with retrofit.]

Any help please?

```
@Multipart
@POST("project/create")
fun createProject(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Part("title") title: String,
    @Part img: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part("release_date") releaseDate: String,
    @Part("contributors[]") contributors: MutableList<Contributor>
): Single<Response<String>>
```

Class Contributor

```
class Contributor : Serializable{

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
var id: Int = 0

@SerializedName("role")
@Expose
var role: String = ""
```

}

Comment: follow this answer you will get result. I did it and it works for me. check wasi Sadam answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553210/retrofit-2-multipart-image-upload-with-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the only way worked for me.

First Created Hashmap and mapped my data on this way

```
val contributorsMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    for((index, contributor) in contributorList.withIndex()){

        contributorsMap["contributors[${index}][id]"] = "${contributor.id}"
        contributorsMap["contributors[${index}][role]"] = contributor.role

    }
```

Then updated my function parameter to @PartMap instead

```
@Multipart
@POST("project/create")
fun createProject(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Part("title") title: String,
    @Part img: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part("release_date") releaseDate: String,
    @PartMap contributors: HashMap<String, String>,
): Single<Response<String>>
```

Comment: What about when one of the fields is an image? `contributors[?][image] = <IMG>` How do you add that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @partMap

```
@PartMap() Map<String, List<Contributor>> contibutors
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
            val contributorsMap: HashMap<String, RequestBody> = HashMap()

            for((index, contributor) in parts.withIndex()){

                contributorsMap["contributors[${index}][id]"] = contributor.id.toString().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
                contributorsMap["contributors[${index}][role]"] = contributor.role.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use @Field

```
@Field("contributors[]") contributors: MutableList<Contributor>
```

Comment: It says @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding