# Retrofit POST List of objects and List<MultipartBody.Part>

Tags: java, android, serialization, retrofit, okhttp

**Retrofit 2.4.0**

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

I need to POST a List of objects and a list of pictures in the same request, like this :

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/debug/{id}/")
Call<ItemResponse> uploadItems(
        @Path("id") int id,
        @Part("items[]") List<Item> items,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> pictures);
```

Server side the list of items are not serialized correctly :

```
{
  "items": [
    "{"description":"desc1","id":1,"title":"title1"}",
    "{"description":"desc2","id":2,"title":"title2"}",
    "{"description":"desc3","id":3,"title":"title3"}"
  ],
  "picture1": {
    "name": "picture1",
    "size": "315.777KB"
  },
  "picture2": {
    "name": "picture2",
    "size": "207.821KB"
  }
}
```

The problem seems to be with using @Part.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't you just replace
`@Part("items[]")` with `@Part`? Then you will get the same structure in JSON response as the picture's list structure.

Comment: If I do this an error is thrown : @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #2)

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. I think that this solution will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951111/14056755. 

TL;DR You have to user @PartMap annotation for the list of objects existing along with the Multipart objects.